# How can I quantity feature importance while performing unsupervised clustering with mixed data types?

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, features

I wanted to cluster data points into 2 clusters, I am using clustmix package from R
I wanted to understand importance of each of the feature, I have 203 features. I have tried featureimp package from R , but it's more focussed around using misclassification rate to define importance. Is it a correct way to identify the feature importance of not

Any suggestions are invited

Comment: Hi @ashishpople, welcome to the site. You could train a logistic regression classifier using the clusters as labels, and then compute the predictor importance, e.g. with the [`varImp` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-92/topics/varImp).

Comment: For a complete tutorial on logistic regression, including variable importance, you can check [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/01/machine-learning-with-r-a-complete-guide-to-logistic-regression/).